Fallo en la variable request de laravel con multiples inputs
tengo la siguiente situación en laravel: cree un formulario con un for en la vista que itera 500 veces
 @for ($i = 0; $i < 500; $i++)
  <tr id="dia_itinerario_{{ $i }}">
    <td>
          <input class="form-control" id="dia_{{ $i }}" name="dia_{{ $i }}">                          
    </td>
  </tr>

Ahora, cuando intento recuperar en el contralador, a traves de la variable request, en ella solo hay almacenado hasta la variable "dia_248". ¿ Por qué el request no almacena las 500 variables, y como puedo solucionar el problema? Gracias de antemano.

verifica so tiene paginacion el view de la variable... verifica si php.ini tiene limite en la cantidad de variables recibidas, verifica que en el html esten todos los 500 input

Muchas gracias, eso solucionó mi problema, aumentar el limite en la cantidad de variables en php.ini

bueno he agregado una respuesta, con algunos datos que a lo mejo te interesen.

tambien si alguna de las respuesta que te han dado te sirve puedes marcar esa respuesta como resuelta.

puede estar ocurriendo varias cosas:

Es comun que si tienes un plugin o sistema de paginacion, la paginacion sea interactiva y cargue mediante ajax las pagina en el momento en que navegues a travez de ellas y no cargue todo desde el inicio.

Otro Motivo puede ser Limitaciones en la configuracion del servidor PHP, para ser más exactos en el archivo php.ini (la ubicacion varia dependiendo del Sistema operativo o forma de instalación) ejemplo:



/etc/php.ini
/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini (for Apache with PHP 7.4)
/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini (for CLI with PHP 7.4)
/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

Y esto se resuelve:
max_input_vars = 5000

Adicional a esta configuración tambien suelo sugerir otras configuraciones que ayudan a evitar problemas o conflictos entre configuracion y hardware:
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 2G
max_file_uploads = 100
allow_url_fopen = On
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 600M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
max_input_vars = 5000
date.timezone= America/Panama
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = on
display_startup_errors = on
html_errors = On
session.gc_maxlifetime = 2592000 ;;30 días aproximadamente
session.cache_expire = 2592000 ;;30 días aproximadamente

Estas configuracion son especificas para entornos de desarrollo local, en donde aveces por culpa de un equipo modesto, los request, o la ejecucion de nuestros script suelen ralentizarce
